# Syncing multple requests (user actions) with Backbone and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, synchronization, backbone.js

The problem resides on building an architecture with Backbone and Rails
that handles syncing multiple actions to the server.
Assume the model is define on both Rails and Backbone.

I have an update and destroy operations on a model and I need them to synced
with the server on a user action (button click). On another part of the webapp, 
these actions on this same model are synced on the moment they
made (easy, just send a restful ajax http request).
But in the first case, I can't really figure out an easy, stateless and atomic/transactional
save of the several actions (requests) the user took.

- Sending multiple requests to the server makes the save non-atomic and a bit of non stateless.
- Sending one big request with the actions formatted makes parsing on the server necessary.

So, is there another better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice way to handle multiple requests at once is at https://github.com/railscasts/414-batch-api-requests

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple updates, on different resources, as one atomic transaction, that is not REST.

So, of course, you will have to orchestrate the parameters and the requests in Rails. (but it's not about parsing, since you'll send JSON, more about creating a format for the aggregated parameters and figuring out what to do on the Rails side).